# How to find the address of a value in an 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pixel, grayscale

I found a max_value (grayscale 2D array [50,200]) with

```
max = numpy.amax(matrice)
```

so it gives me a value.
Now I want to know were I can find this value.
I tried this code:

```
for x in range (1,50):  
for y in range (1,200):
if matrice[x,y]==max:
print ("[%s,%s]",x,y)
```

but it gives me an error message:

"for y in range (1,200):
      IndentationError: expected an indented block"

Can someone tell me what is the error or how I can find the address of this pixel?

Comment: I solved it...

for x in range (1,50):  
     for y in range (1,200):
           if matrice[x,y]==max:
                  print ("[%s,%s]",x,y)

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you did not indent the line after the colon, so the syntax should look something like this:

```
for x in range (1,50):  
    for y in range (1,200):
        if matrice[x,y]==max:
            print ("[%s,%s]",x,y)
```

Try looking up the rules for indentation in Python, if you are in doubt about when you should use indentation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give tab indentation for each block

```
for x in range (1,50):  
    for y in range (1,200):
        if matrice[x,y]==max:
            print ("[%s,%s]",x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can vectorise your logic.

```
A = np.random.randint(0, 10, (5, 5))

print(A)

# [[4 9 3 0 8]
#  [5 0 3 9 0]
#  [2 2 4 1 5]
#  [3 5 9 0 0]
#  [9 5 7 9 5]]

res = np.argwhere(A==np.amax(A))

print(res)

# [[0 1]
#  [1 3]
#  [3 2]
#  [4 0]
#  [4 3]]
```